# Concatenating matrices from different .mat files with same variable names

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate the vectors from these respective .mat files, but the problem is the vectors have identical names so when trying to concatenate them, one of the vectors concatenates to itself. All of the vectors are the same width, but one is 50 rows long and the other is 200 rows long. This shouldn't be much of a problem since am concatenating vertically.

```
% Load in file(s) we want to use
load('00_CTO27-Jul-2016_ALSAData.mat');
load('01_CTO27-Jul-2016_ALSAData.mat');

%---------------- Vector Set-up ----------------%
% Concatenate vectors
ACC = vertcat(ACCvector, ACCvector);
Gender = vertcat(GenderVector, GenderVector);
RT = vertcat(RTvector, RTvector);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about loading one, assigning the values to the new vectors, then load the second and concatenate.

Comment: You could also use this form: `s = load('...')`, `s` will be a structure with variables of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`load`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) function can return a struct with the variables of the file. So in your case you could do this

```
% Load in file(s) we want to use
a = load('00_CTO27-Jul-2016_ALSAData.mat');
b = load('01_CTO27-Jul-2016_ALSAData.mat');

%---------------- Vector Set-up ----------------%
% Concatenate vectors
ACC = vertcat(a.ACCvector, b.ACCvector);
Gender = vertcat(a.GenderVector, b.GenderVector);
RT = vertcat(a.RTvector, b.RTvector);
```

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for!